# "Refresh Tab" Works For Subtab, But Not Main Tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, tab, refresh, navigationmixin.navigate

I've created an LWC wrapped in an Aura Component so that I can navigate directly to it as a tab (see 2nd part of answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/280602/89720)). Everything works just fine, except that: when I'm 1) opening it as a subtab, the "Refresh Tab" works just fine; but when I'm 2) opening it as a main tab, "Refresh Tab" does nothing:

[image]

Here's the difference between the 2 places I'm using it (remember this is the same exact component, just used in 2 slightly different contexts):

1. **As a subtab (#1)** - I'm Navigating from one component ("Order Det...") in the screenshot and opening a new subtab ("ZCR") - this is all within the main Account tab (shown here as "Richard Doyle").
2. **As a main tab (#2)** - the main "ZCR" tab that #2 in the screenshot is pointing to is opened from a record list - I've edited the content of the page that opens when clicking on one of the items in the record list (a Record Page using my custom object). I replaced the default content with my Aura-wrapped LWC component.

**Why is "Refresh Tab" working in #1 but not #2? Is there any workaround for this?**

I've even tried capturing the refresh event in the Aura component and then manually refreshing via `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`, but the event never seems to fire. I tried something like:

```
<!-- Aura Wrapper - Component -->
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:appHostable, lightning:isUrlAddressable, force:hasRecordId">

    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{! c.handleRefreshView }" />
    ...
    ...
</aura:component>

<!-- Aura Wrapper - Controller-->
handleRefreshView: function (component) {
    alert('refreshView event triggered!');
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
},
```

And the `handleRefreshView` handler never gets hit.

**Which event gets triggered when "Refresh Tab" is clicked? Can I capture this?**

Comment: Any update on this - @sfdcfox, any input?

Comment: So #1 is occurring through `NavigationMixin` from another custom component while #2 is actually just an object's record page (which your component happens to be on?)

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - sry for the delay - yes, correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lightning:tabRefreshed` event.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_events_tabrefreshed.htm) for more detail.